# Set "SF UI Display Bold" as label font

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, ios9

I have a problem with setting the font of my label to SF UI Display Bold.

I don't wanna set this durable, only if a boolean is false.

```
if (value.messageReaded == false) {
    cell.subjectLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"SF UI Display Bold", size: 17.0)
}
```

Unfortunately, my approach isn't working with this font.

Does somebody of you know the correct title of the "SF UI Display Bold" font in swift?

Thanks!

Comment: The Display variant of SF is used for large displays of the text. Not for iPhone labels.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Theoretically you could use the font by calling its font name directly. The font name for that font is `.SFUIDisplay-Bold`.

However Apple discourages this approach and says that these font names are private and subject to change at any time.

The official way to use the San Francisco fonts is to call `systemFont` which automatically gives you the San Francisco font:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
```

To get a lighter or bolder font you can request the font weight:

```
let mediumFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
let lightFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
let boldFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
```

There is a ton of font weights to choose from:

```
UIFont.Weight.ultraLight
UIFont.Weight.thin
UIFont.Weight.light
UIFont.Weight.regular
UIFont.Weight.medium
UIFont.Weight.semibold
UIFont.Weight.bold
UIFont.Weight.heavy
UIFont.Weight.black
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the system will automatically pick the Display or Text variant for you, based on the point size you request.  Based on the WWDC presentation, if you request the system font of size < 20 you will get the Text variant, and if you request the system font at size >= 20 you will get the Display variant.

Comment: Is there any non-hacky way to get “SF UI Display” for font sizes less than 20?

Answer (score 2):

As per Joern's answer updated for Swift 4:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
let mediumFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
let lightFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
let boldFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
```

Also see [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont.weight)